# What's wrong with this audio?

Tags: linux, audio, codec

I've tried to use an at91-sama5d2 and an max9880 codec. Since drivers where lacking I've written my own driver and now finally got sound. However it sounds really bad, see:

[Sound quality example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEhua4u-K5w)

I'm failing to identify the error here. What kind of error makes this sound so bad?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but requests for debugging non-existant code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: Make sure your endianness is correct .. to simplify that try to render a bit depth of 8 bit instead of 16 bit before solving for 16 bit or higher ... also get working single channel ( mono ) before attacking stereo ... hard to tell listening to your sample audio clip however a helpful missing hint is is the rendering getting sped up or slowed down or no ... update your question with these data points to better help us help U ... I know your frustration as I implemented aac audio using just ISO spec and its a real eye opening life experience plucking compressed binary audio from payload packets

Comment: its extremely helpful to use a nice simple sin curve as your input audio so the values are known and predictable ... this will give you immediate feedback as to whether the above potential issues I mentioned are correctly handled or not ... that is write some code to generate your input audio curve so you know exactly what each sample should be

Comment: You should probably show the relevant code for data stream processing. Adobe got in some trouble a while back by using `memcpy` instead of `memmove` on overlapping buffers. The runtime uses a different algorithm  for `memcpy` and `memmove`. I think it is a SSE4.1 instruction that copies bytes in reverse order, so `src` was being overwritten by `dest` before the low source bytes were copied. Also see [Strange sound on mp3 flash website](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477) on RedHat's issue tracker.